# converting numbers to metric unit in python

Tags: python, math, scientific-computing

when doing this in python `100*0.000001` I got `9.999999999999999e-05`
What I need to do to get `1e-05`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

floating point numbers are not exact.  You could represent it as `1e-4` when printing, or use `Decimal` to get an exact value.   e.g.

```
>>> print '{:4.0e}'.format(100*0.000001)
1e-04
```

or

```
>>> Decimal(100)*Decimal('0.000001')
Decimal('0.000100')
```

Comment: Actually, they are exact. It's just that floating arithmetic is not our standard arithmetic. Just a nuance.

Comment: @freakish -- when you write `0.000001` you're not guaranteed that literal is different than `0.00000100000000000000000000000001`.  So I would argue that they aren't *exact*.  but I suppose that it depends on how you're looking at it.

Comment: @mgilson Yeah, but it's not that floating arithmetic fails, but conversion. But it doesn't really matter from practical point of view.

Comment: @freakish -- Yes, I suppose that's true.  Converting from literals to floating point numbers is what is *inexact*.  Coupled with the differences in floating point arithmetic and you get the behavior above.  Anyway, It's easier to say floating point numbers are not exact ;-).  Practically it's the same thing and easier to grasp.

Answer (score 0):

Don't do the multiplication:

```
>>> 100e-7
1e-05
```

Realize though that [0.1 is an infinitely repeating number in binary](http://www.exploringbinary.com/why-0-point-1-does-not-exist-in-floating-point/) and you will discover approximations other artifacts before too long:

```
>>> 100e-7*.1
1.0000000000000002e-06
```

Then just deal with the issue in formating the output:

```
>>> '{:e}'.format(100*0.000001)
'1.000000e-04'
>>> '{:e}'.format(100*0.0000001)
'1.000000e-05'
>>> '{:e}'.format(100*0.00000001)
'1.000000e-06'
```